# How to change code style in IntelliJ to have a good wrap for JSX with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, jsx

In the IDE Intellij, I want to change my code style when I press `option + command + L` (MacOs key) from this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ParallaxProvider> <BrowserRouter> <Routes> <Route path="/" element={<Layout><App/></Layout>}/> <Route path="confidentialite"
                                                                                                                       element={
                                                                                                                           <Layout><Confidentialite/></Layout>}/>
    <Route path="*" element={<Layout><App/></Layout>}/> </Routes> </BrowserRouter> </ParallaxProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root"));
```

To this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ParallaxProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={
                    <Layout>
                        <App/>
                    </Layout>
                }/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </ParallaxProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I do not see the good settings here:

[image: Settings Intellij Code Style Javascript]

Comment: It can't be done via settings. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010546960/comments/360002834900